# NDSolve returns different answer for different value of xmax

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have solved a differential equation by using `NDSolve` with `xmax=3`

```
ydum = x/L[t]; 
expr1 = Expand[(1/c^2)*D[\[Psi][ydum, t], {t, 2}] - 
     D[\[Psi][ydum, t], {x, 2}] + ((m^2*c^2)/h^2)*\[Psi][ydum, 
       t] /. \[Psi][ydum, t] -> \[Psi][y, t] /. x -> y*L[t]]
m = 1; 
c = 1; 
h = 1; 
\[Omega] = 1; 
L[t_] := 2 + Sin[\[Omega]*t];

 sol = NDSolve[{expr1 == 0, \[Psi][0, t] == 0, \[Psi][1, t] == 
    0, \[Psi][y, 0] == 
    Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + \[Pi]^2 h^2/L[0]^2] L[0])]
      Sin[ \[Pi] y]}, \[Psi], {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 3}]
```

Then I plot this with `Plot3D`

```
Plot3D[Abs[Evaluate[\[Psi][y, t] /. sol]], {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {y, t, \[Psi]}]
```

[image]

Then I changed the `xmax` of my `NDSolve` to `10` and plot the answer still with `t` ranging from 0 to 3

```
sol = NDSolve[{expr1 == 0, \[Psi][0, t] == 0, \[Psi][1, t] == 
        0, \[Psi][y, 0] == 
        Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + \[Pi]^2 h^2/L[0]^2] L[0])]
          Sin[ \[Pi] y]}, \[Psi], {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The 2 graphs are clearly different. From my understanding, changing the range in which a differential equation is evaluated shouldn't change the answer (I have also tried it with simpler differential equation and this didn't happen). Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Notice though the equation isn't exactly the same, the underlying issue is.

Comment: Could you explain what is  `xmax` in the code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, it's the range of the independent variable (t in this case) in which the differential equation is evaluated.
I just noticed that I wrote `xmax=10` in my first equation, but the plot belongs to `xmax=3` though.