# NDSolve evaluates differential equation beyond the specified range

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

This is a continuation of my previous post [NDSolve returns different answer for different value of xmax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263275/ndsolve-returns-different-answer-for-different-value-of-xmax)

I have managed to resolve the problem of NDSolve returning different answer for different value of `xmax` by adding the 4th b.c. `D[\[Psi][y, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0` (refer to [How do I use more steps to approximate the boundary condition with NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156651/how-do-i-use-more-steps-to-approximate-the-boundary-condition-with-ndsolve)).

Here is my code :

```
ydum = x/L[t];
expr1 = 1/c^2 D[\[Psi][ydum, t], {t, 2}] - 
     D[\[Psi][ydum, t], {x, 2}] + (m^2 c^2)/
      h^2 \[Psi][ydum, t] /. \[Psi][ydum, t] -> \[Psi][y, t] /. 
   x -> y L[t] // Expand
m = 1;
c = 1;
h = 1;
\[Omega] = 1;
L[t_] := 2 + Sin[\[Omega] t];
sol = NDSolve[{expr1 == 0, \[Psi][0, t] == 0, \[Psi][1, t] == 
    0, \[Psi][y, 0] == 
    Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + \[Pi]^2 h^2/L[0]^2] L[0])]
      Sin[ \[Pi] y], D[\[Psi][y, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0}, \[Psi], {y, 
   0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I received a warning from NDSolve : [image]

However, another problem comes up. when I `plot` the result :

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Abs@Evaluate[\[Psi][y, t]] /. sol}, {y , 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 10}}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

It seems that NDSolve has decided to solve the PDE outside of the range that I have specified `{y,0,1}`, and this somehow leads to the solution blowing up at late time (`t`). I managed to resolve this by adding `DirichletCondition[\[Psi][y, t] == 0, y > 1]` in my `NDSolve` :

```
sol = NDSolve[{expr1 == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][y, t] == 0, y > 1], \[Psi][1, t] == 
    0, \[Psi][0, t] == 0, \[Psi][y, 0] == 
    Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + \[Pi]^2 h^2/L[0]^2] L[0])]
      Sin[ \[Pi] y], D[\[Psi][y, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0}, \[Psi], {y, 
   0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

It says that the `DirichletCondition` is ignored anyway but this resolves the problem above as can be seen in the `plot`
[image]

To sum up, my question is why does NDSolve evaluate solution outside of the specified range (which I have set to be `{y,0,1}` and why does adding `DirichletCondition[\[Psi][y, t] == 0, y > 1]` solve the problem when *Mathematica* says that it ignores it?

**Additional Question**

I have come across the `NeumannValue` for specifying derivative boundary condition. I tried to use this to replace this b.c. `D[\[Psi][y, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0`. Here is my code :

```
sol = NDSolve[{expr1 == NeumannValue[0, t == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][y, t] == 0, y > 1], \[Psi][1, t] == 
    0, \[Psi][0, t] == 0, \[Psi][y, 0] == 
    Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + \[Pi]^2 h^2/L[0]^2] L[0])]
      Sin[ \[Pi] y]}, \[Psi], {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

But this doesn't resolve my previous problem ([NDSolve returns different answer for different value of xmax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263275/ndsolve-returns-different-answer-for-different-value-of-xmax)). I would like to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NDSolve` does not compute the solution outside of the domain. However, the interpolating function `NDSolve` returns can be evaluated outside of the solution domain. In those cases it extrapolates the solution outside the domain. Now, why does adding a `DirichletConditon` change that. Well, when you add a `DirichletCondition` you (implicitly) force the solution method to be the finite element method. For the finite element method the possibility of extrapolation of the result is switched off. This is done because in case of the finite element method we know nothing beyond the domain. In the FEM case, the boundary conditions are all we know at the boundary.