# Worrisome result from pdetoode method in solving moving boundary condition problem

Tags: differential-equations

The problem I am trying to solve is the following :

$$(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+1)\psi(x,t)=0$$

$$\psi (0,t)=\psi(L(t),t)=0$$

$$\psi(x,0)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{c\sqrt{1+\pi^2/4}}} sin(\pi \frac{x}{2})$$

$$\frac{d\psi (x,t)}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0}=0$$

$$L(t)=2+sin(\omega t)$$

I have used the pdetoode method as was used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130962/how-to-solve-a-system-of-pdes-with-zip-condition) to solve this problem and here is my code (some codes might be redundant as I copied and modified the code from the link above) :

```
ydum = x/L[t];
eqn1 = 1/c^2 D[\[Psi][ydum, t], {t, 2}] - 
      D[\[Psi][ydum, t], {x, 2}] + (m^2 c^2)/h^2 \[Psi][ydum, t] == 
     0 /. \[Psi][ydum, t] -> \[Psi][y, t] /. x -> y L[t] // Expand

m = 1;
c = 1;
h = 1;
\[Omega] = 1;
L[t_] := 2 + Sin[\[Omega] t];
bc = {\[Psi][0, t] == 0, \[Psi][1, t] == 0};
ic = {\[Psi][y, 0] == 
    Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + \[Pi]^2 h^2/L[0]^2] L[0])]
      Sin[ \[Pi] y], D[\[Psi][y, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0};
points = 25;
xdifforder = 4;
{yL, yR} = domain = {0, 1};
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
pto = pdetoode[\[Psi][y, t], t, grid, xdifforder];
remove = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
{ode, odebc, odeic} = MapAt[remove, pto /@ {eqn1, bc, ic}, 1];
soll = NDSolveValue[{ode, odebc, odeic[[2]], odeic[[1]]}, \[Psi] /@ 
    grid, {t, 0, 50}];
sol1 = rebuild[#, grid, -1] &@soll
Manipulate[
 Plot[sol1[y, t] /. y -> y L[t], {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 10}], {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

The solution grows larger in time and this makes me anxious. Is this how it's supposed to be or is there something wrong with my code?

I have also solved this problem without the use of pdetoode (check out my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263326/ndsolve-evaluates-differential-equation-beyond-the-specified-range) ) and I got different result :
[image]

I greatly appreciate anyone who would point out my error in both methods.

Comment: The grid is too coarse, try e.g. `points = 200; xdifforder = 2;`. Also, it's better to observe a smaller time interval first e.g. `{t, 0, 5}`.

Comment: Thanks! Now the solution doesn't get larger in time.
However, when I ramp up the `$\omega$` to `1000`, NDSolveValue spits out an error :
`NDSolveValue::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.`
How do I fix this?
(By the way, what does `xdifforder` mean in pdetoode?)

Comment: 1. As to the icfail message, it's because you're currently discretize the system to a DAE system, to avoid it, you need to handle the b.c. in a more complicated way, see e.g. this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871  and this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184285/1871 2. `xdifforder` sets the value of `DifferenceOrder` option of `NDSolve\`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`, it's the order of difference formula for spatial discretization.